# Github not recognizing CNAME

Tags: github, cname

I added a CNAME file to my repo, and under my settings, it didn't update the domain. It still says

```
Your site is published at http://username.github.io/repo
```

Instead of

```
Your site is published at www.domain.com
```

I've configured my settings with namecheap, and it takes me to "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here." So it's being associated with github via my DNS settings, but github doesn't seem to be picking up on the fact that there's a CNAME file inside the repo.

Comment: This has nothing to do with DNS. It's entirely an internal Github issue. What did Github's support people say when you contacted them?